# Printing prime factors of a number using a "points system"

Tags: python

We've been given a challenge to write a program that prints prime factors of an input number. We're given an outline: the program checks for factors of the original number; each such factor gets one point. Then, if that factor is prime, it gets another point. Each factor with two points gets printed.

Here's what I have so far.

```
print('Please enter a number')
x = int(input('Number:'))
a = int(0)
b = int(0)
c = int(1)
d = int(0)
counter = int(0)
while (a < x-1):
    a = a + 1
    counter = 0
    if (x / a % 1 == 0):
        b = a
        counter = counter + 1
        while(c < b - 1):
            c = c + 1
            if((b / c) % 1 != 0):
                d = b
                counter = counter + 1
                if(counter == 2):
                    print(d)
```

With input of 15, I get 3 and 5, but also 15 (wrong).  With 24, I get 3, 4, 6, 8, and 12; several of these are not prime.

I believe the issue lies somewhere in the innermost loop, but I can't pinpoint the problem.

At first the issue was I wasn't resetting the "counter", so future factors would exceed 2 "points" and nothing would print. I fixed that by resetting it before it enters the innermost loop, but sadly, that didn't fix the problem.

I've also tried getting rid of 'b' and 'd' and just using two variables to see if I was somehow overcomplicating it, but that didn't help either.

EDIT: Edited slightly for clarity.

Comment: Your variables names are not very informative

Comment: And you don't need to convert int literals to int every time.

Comment: Also, the loop can be recast as `for a in range(x - 1):`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Sorry about that, I'm coming from C, that's probably why everything looks a bit weird :(

Comment: I've never heard of casting an int literal to an int being necessary in C either.

Comment: Your problem description is not clear -- there are too many things referred to as "number" and "factor".  Take an example input of 5, with the "given number" being 15.  We now have that 5 is, indeed, a factor of 15, so it gets one point.  5 is also prime, so it gets a second point, and is printed.  However, we now hit the phrase "with all the possible factors."  Factors of *what*, exactly?  We have an input number and a magically "given" number (source unknown).

Comment: "I'm coming from C" is no excuse to use meaningless variable names.  Remember that you're asking people for help; make it easy for us to follow your problem statement and coding attempt.  See [Jon Skeet's guide](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Also, your program does *not* produce the listed problems: entering 15 does *not* include 15 in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sentence was enough of a clue for me to unravel the rest of your posting.  Your main problems are loop handling and logic of determining a prime factor.

In general, I see your program design as

- Input target number
- Find each factor of the number
- For each factor, determine whether the factor is prime.  If so, print it.

Now, let's look at the innermost loop:

```
    while(c < b - 1):
        c = c + 1
        if((b / c) % 1 != 0):
            d = b
            counter = counter + 1
            if(counter == 2):
                print(d)
```

As a styling note, please explain why you are building `for` logic from `while` loops; this makes your program harder to read.  Variable `d` does nothing for you.  Also, your handling of `counter` is an extra complication: any time you determine that `b` is a prime number, then simply print it.

The main problem is your logical decision point: you look for factors of `b`.  However, rather than waiting until you know `b` is prime, you print it as soon as you discover *any* smaller number that doesn't divide `b`.  Since `b-1` is rarely a factor of `b` (only when b=2), then you will erroneously identify *any* `b` value as a prime number.

Instead, you have to wait until you have tried *all* possible factors.  Something like this:

```
is_prime = True
for c in range(2, b):
    if b % c == 0:
        is_prime = False
        break

if is_prime:
    print(b)
```

There are more "Pythonic" ways to do this, but I think that this is more within your current programming sophistication.  If it's necessary to fulfill your assignment, you can add a point only when you've found no factors, and then check the count after you leave the `for` loop.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *entirely* sure I follow you're problem description, but here is my attempt at interpreting it as best I can:

```
import math

def is_factor(n,m):
    return m % n == 0

def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))

def assign_points(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if is_factor(i,n) and is_prime(i):
            print('two points for: ', i)
        elif is_factor(i,n):
            print('one point for: ', i)

print(assign_points(15))
```